# OpenGL: wglGetProcAddress always returns NULL

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to create an OpenGL program which uses shaders. I tried using the following code to load the shader functions, but `wglGetProcAddress` *always* returns 0 no matter what I do.
The rest of the program works as normal when not using the shader functions.

```
HDC g_hdc;
HGLRC g_hrc;

PFNGLATTACHSHADERPROC   glpf_attachshader;
PFNGLCOMPILESHADERPROC  glpf_compileshader;
PFNGLCREATEPROGRAMPROC  glpf_createprogram;
PFNGLCREATESHADERPROC   glpf_createshader;
PFNGLDELETEPROGRAMPROC  glpf_deleteprogram;
PFNGLDELETESHADERPROC   glpf_deleteshader;
PFNGLDETACHSHADERPROC   glpf_detachshader;
PFNGLLINKPROGRAMPROC    glpf_linkprogram;
PFNGLSHADERSOURCEPROC   glpf_shadersource;
PFNGLUSEPROGRAMPROC     glpf_useprogram;

void GL_Init(HDC dc)
{
    //create pixel format
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = 
    {
        sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR), 
        1,
        PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER, 
        PFD_TYPE_RGBA, 
        32,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0,
        32, 0, 0,
        PFD_MAIN_PLANE,
        0, 0, 0, 0
    };

    //choose + set pixel format
    int pixfmt = ChoosePixelFormat(dc, &pfd);
    if (pixfmt && SetPixelFormat(dc, pixfmt, &pfd))
    {
        //create GL render context
        if (g_hrc = wglCreateContext(dc))
        {
            g_hdc = dc;

            //select GL render context
            wglMakeCurrent(dc, g_hrc);

            //get function pointers     
            glpf_attachshader   = (PFNGLATTACHSHADERPROC)   wglGetProcAddress("glAttachShader");
            glpf_compileshader  = (PFNGLCOMPILESHADERPROC)  wglGetProcAddress("glCompileShader");
            glpf_createprogram  = (PFNGLCREATEPROGRAMPROC)  wglGetProcAddress("glCreateProgram");
            glpf_createshader   = (PFNGLCREATESHADERPROC)   wglGetProcAddress("glCreateShader");
            glpf_deleteprogram  = (PFNGLDELETEPROGRAMPROC)  wglGetProcAddress("glDeleteProgram");
            glpf_deleteshader   = (PFNGLDELETESHADERPROC)   wglGetProcAddress("glDeleteShader");
            glpf_detachshader   = (PFNGLDETACHSHADERPROC)   wglGetProcAddress("glDetachShader");
            glpf_linkprogram    = (PFNGLLINKPROGRAMPROC)    wglGetProcAddress("glLinkProgram");
            glpf_shadersource   = (PFNGLSHADERSOURCEPROC)   wglGetProcAddress("glShaderSource");
            glpf_useprogram     = (PFNGLUSEPROGRAMPROC)     wglGetProcAddress("glUseProgram");
        }
    }
}
```

I know this may be a possible duplicate, but on most of the other posts the error was because of simple mistakes (like calling `wglGetProcAddress` before `wglMakeCurrent`). I'm in a bit of an unique situation - any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried calling GetLastError to get a hint as to why?

Comment: Yes I found `ChoosePixelFormat` causes a system error code 6 ("The handle was invalid"). But apparently this is irrelevant because it happens in all of the Nehe tutorials too.

Comment: I would recommend that you query `GL_VERSION` and `GL_EXTENSIONS` strings before your query the pointers and check if you actually got the context you expected. If windows for some reason fell back to its builtin GL1.1 renderer, it would totally explain the results you got. Using GL function pointers whose existence is not implied by the GL Version or advertised by the extensions string would be undefined behavior anyway, since even non-zero return value of `GetProcAddress` does not guarantee the functionality being available.

Comment: @derhass `GL_VERSION` query says I have version 1.3.0 - does this version not support the extensions I am trying to get?

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah: No. The function pointers you query for are OpenGL 2.0 core functions. Shaders were previously available as extensions to GL1.5 (but with a moderately different API). However, it is extremely unlikely that any GL1.3 implementation would expose shader extensions. What kind of GPU is this?

Comment: @derhass this is kinda embarrassing... it's a 9-year old Dell with integrated graphics on a Pentium M (oh dear :S).

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah: Well OK. Integrated graphics tends to be a bit behind discrete GPUs, and it was worse back than. The programmable pipeline is available on AMD and NVidia desktop GPUs since 10 years or so...

Comment: @derhass so the bottom line is, there is no way I could do this... well thanks for the help anyway, really appreciated!

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah: Well, there is no way you do this with that GPU. However, you could (in theory) use some software GL implementation. It would be _very_ slow (at least compared to some reasonably modern GPU). [Mesa](http://mesa3d.org) does implement such a software rasterizer. However, I haven't tried to built it on windows for few years, but it was possible a few years ago.

Comment: Where is `wglGetProcAddress` defined?

Answer (score 1):

You are requesting a 32-bit Z-Buffer in this code. That will probably throw you onto the GDI software rasterizer (which implements exactly **0** extensions). You can use 32-bit depth buffers on modern hardware, but most of the time you cannot do it using the ***default*** framebuffer, you have to use FBOs.

I have seen some drivers accept 32-bit depth only to fallback to the closest matching 24-bit pixel format, while others simply refuse to give a hardware pixel format at all (this is probably your case). If this is in fact your problem, a quick investigation of your GL strings (`GL_RENDERER`, `GL_VERSION`, `GL_VENDOR`) should make it obvious.

24-bit Depth + 8-bit Stencil is pretty much universally supported, this is the first depth/stencil size you should try.

Answer (score -3):

You could use glew to do that kind of work for you.
Or maybe you don't want?

EDIT:
You could maybe use glext.h then. Or at least look in it and copy paste what interest you.

I'm not an expert I just remember having that kind of problem and try to remind what was conected to it.

Comment: Maybe, yes. But I think glew is a bit over-the-top. I just want to load a minimal set of functions myself.